# Moving a conductor with the presence of both E & B fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, classical-electrodynamics

[image]

If a conductor is charged from an exterior electric field, moved in a magnetic field perpendicular to the E-Field, the velocity's direction is also perpendicular to both the B-field and E-field.

- How would the Lorentz force disrupt the accumulated charges by the
  edges?
- Could the Lorentz force surpass the electrostatic forces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How would the Lorentz force disrupt the accumulated charges by the
>   edges?

It should decrease or increase charge separation depending on the direction of the magnetic field (up or down).

> Could the Lorentz force surpass the electrostatic forces?

It can't "surpass" the electrostatic forces, because electrostatic forces are responsible for the separation of charges that brings about the Lorentz force in the first place.

Comment: The first statement makes perfect sense, but I'm confused with the following: "because electrostatic forces are responsible for the separation of charges that brings about the Lorentz force in the first place."  How does the seperated charge bring about the Lorentz force? Isn't it F = qE + qv x B

Comment: To my understanding, the motion of the conductor with the charges within it, bring about the Lorentz force.

Comment: @UnkownConstants Without the electric field, the conductor would be neutral and there won't be any charge q the Lorentz force would act on. When the electric field is applied, electrons are pushed to one side of the conductor leaving positive ions on the other: now we have two  moving charges the Lorentz force could act on.

Comment: „It should decrease or increase charge separation depending on the direction of the magnetic field (up or down).“ Shouldn’t the external field deflect the charges - electrons in on side and protons in the other and rotate by this a little bit the body?

Comment: @HolgerFiedler The magnetic field should exert equal forces on both positive and negative charges, so the net force on the conductor should be zero.

Comment: @V.F. The Lorentz force has opposite signs for negative and positive charges particles.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler Does not that mean that the forces acting on negative and positive charges will cancel each other and the net force acting on the conductor will be zero?

Comment: @V.F. No, because it’s a dipole. There is definitely a torque. Futhermore the Lorentz force is not only of different signs but of different value and the charged conductor moves sideways.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler If the charges are moving away from us (into the page) and the magnetic field points up or down (normal to the electric field and to the movement of the charges), the Lorentz forces will be directed to left and right - normal to the direction of the magnetic field and the movement of changes, hence, the dipoles will stretch or shrink, not rotate.

Comment: @V.F.  May be I’m missunderstanding something, but the questioner says “the velocity's direction is also perpendicular to both the B-field and E-field.”

Comment: @HolgerFiedler Yes, when the charges are moving away from us (Z), electric field is pointing to the right (X) and magnetic field is pointing up (Y), the velocity's direction is perpendicular to both E-field and B-field.  The Lorentz force should be perpendicular to the velocity of charges (Z) and the direction of B-field (Y), so it is acting along X (same as E-field) - stretching or shrinking dipoles, which have X orientation to start with.